# Spring Jackson JsonViews - Get Fields based on JsonView

Tags: java, spring, jackson, json-view

I've got an entity with a number of fields and with a JsonView specified:

```
public class Client {

   @JsonView(Views.ClientView.class)
   @Column(name = "clientid")
   private long clientId;

   @JsonView(Views.ClientView.class)
   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name

   @JsonView(Views.SystemView.class)
   @Column(name = "istest")
   private boolean istest;
   .........

}
```

The views are defined as follows:

```
public class Views {

  public interface SystemView extends ClientView {
  }

  public interface ClientView {
  }
}
```

I also have a simple controller in order to update the client. Since the field `istest` is set to `SystemView`, I don't want the client to update that field.

I've read in order posts, that this has to be done manually by first loading the client and than updating the parameters accordingly (in my case `clientId` and `name`).

Now I want to get a list of fields that I need to update (i.e. the fields marked with `JsonView` as `Views.ClientView.class`). I've tried the following but it's not working:

```
ObjectReader reader = objectMapper.readerWithView(SystemView.class);
ContextAttributes attributes = reader.getAttributes();
```

But, `attributes` is returning without any elements.

Is there a way to get this list of fields based on the View?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access and inspect the annotations of fields in a class with `Reflection` likes:

```
List<Field> annotatedFields = new ArrayList<>();
Field[] fields = Client.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    if (!field.isAnnotationPresent(JsonView.class)) {
        continue;
    }
    JsonView annotation = field.getAnnotation(JsonView.class);
    if (Arrays.asList(annotation.value()).contains(Views.SystemView.class)) {
        annotatedFields.add(field);
    }
}
```

In the above example, `annotatedFields` will contain a list of fields in `Client` class annotated with `JsonView` with a value contains `Views.SystemView.class`.